# unable to change text color in ion-option when interface="popover"

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ion-select

I am using `ion-select` for selecting an option and i want to change the text color of `ion-option`. My code is as below...

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-select interface="popover" [(ngModel)]="selectedGrp" (ionChange)="changeGrp()">  
        <ion-option value="" selected disabled>Select</ion-option>
        <ion-option *ngFor="let item of List;let i = index" [value]="item">{{item.name}} </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

There are no SASS Variables for doing this. I have tried by using css and styles but it's not working. Can any one help me to change the `ion-option` text color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to change the text color (of all `ion-options`) by inserting in `app.scss`

```
.item-radio.item ion-label {
    color: red; //your color here
}
```

For the selected option, insert a `!important` to the color attribute

```
.item-radio-checked.item ion-label {
    color: blue !important; //your color here for selected option
}
```

Comment: its working but before that when i select any option then selected option is set to primary color but after using this selected option color is not updating can you tell me how to do it?